# I am trying to implement long pressing in Swift 3 but it gets terminated

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I want to create a long gestured tap for a UIView using Swift 3 . I've done the following but the problem is when I start tapping my app gets terminated . Any idea why ?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("longTap:"))
        image.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)
    }

    func longTap(sender : UIGestureRecognizer){
        print("Long tap")
        if sender.state == .ended {
            image.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        }
        else if sender.state == .began {
            image.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the title have to do with your posted question? And please [edit] your question to include details about the error. What is the full error message? Which line exactly causes the error?

Comment: Any crash log? add here.

Comment: Thanks . I've found the mistake it was the Selector :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use the `Selector("longTap:")` syntax any longer. Instead use `#selector(ViewController.longTap)`. The problem is that after the big renaming, the selector is no longer named what you expect it to be named. Try running the following in a playground:

```
class Test : NSObject {
    func didLongTap1(sender : UIGestureRecognizer) {
    }
    func didLongTap2(_ sender : Any) {
    }
}

print("\(#selector(Test.didLongTap1))")
print("\(#selector(Test.didLongTap2))")
print("\(Selector("didLongTap1:"))")
```

It prints:

```
didLongTap1WithSender:
didLongTap2:
didLongTap1:
```

Comment: `#selector(longTap)` is sufficient here :)

Comment: @Fogmeister What you've just mentioned is true . But I am quite new to swift . So I'd like to ask you why although the main function has input then we dont have to mention that in #selector(longTap) :)